# In Perl - Need to modify a script to parse all files in a directory

Tags: perl, directory

I have little to no Perl experience, so any assistance is much appreciated. I'm sorry if I'm not giving clear information in the question as I do not have a programming background.

I have a script that will parse a text file, check for a certain number of data points in the text file, then output "# of data points = X". I can get this to run on a single text file, and I can get it to output to a text file which is great.

However, there are 138 text files that I need to parse and analyze the data in number, all in one directory. I'm wondering if rather than running this individual script 138 times I can modify the script to go to the directory, run on each file in it, and output the results together in a text file.

I didn't write the original script, I inherited it and just barely managed to figure out how to get it to run on a single text file.

Comment: We can't help unless you show the code you want to modify. An example of the contents of the data files would also help.

Comment: Post your script, example input, desired output.

Comment: `for %f in (*.*) do perl myscript.pl %f` ... That is, learn how to use your shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a glob, like so.

```
my @files = </path/where/files/are/*>;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    print "working on $file...\n"
    # do stuff with $file;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful. I've been making some progress as a result. 

I'm at a point where I can get the script to print "Working on File..." and all the file-names in the directory. However I'm having trouble getting it to actually run the 'stuff with $file'. Frustratingly, I can run the script for a single file and get it to work. It just doesn't work when I copy that script into the 'stuff with $file' section. 

Regardless, I'm tremendously appreciative!

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is to open 138 file in the same directory, you can open one by one using the "opendir" function, example of a script that open ALL FILES and print all lines :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $directory = '/tmp';

opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
        print "$file\n";
    open (FILE, $file) or die $!;
    while (<FILE>) {
        print $_;
        }
}
closedir(DIR);
```